# Rails Active Admin password without devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

On my rails app, it didn't use Devise because there is no need for registration. But I've added Active Admin to let my team create post etc.

But Devise isn't install so Active Admin is installed without password login for the admin page.
How can I add a login page for the active admin page ?

Comment: No because is used : 
`rails g active_admin:install --skip-users # skips Devise install`

Answer (score 0):

Use `config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!` and `config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user` in initializer settings. So, you need to define methods `authenticate_admin_user!` && `current_admin_user` in `ApplicationController` or change these methods names

Explanation: http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html